# How to check what installed by Ansible?

Tags: virtualbox, ansible

I cloned a Directory from Github and setup that itself called Ansible. Now it did make a virtual machine along with installed many things. I could not save all installed on my virtual box. The script in the end gave following output

```
: ok=29   changed=17   unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Now How do I see what was installed on Virtual Box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add --list-tasks option to the ansible-playbook command to list out a high level tasks been executed by ansible. Which should give you a idea of what ansible has orchestrated on the VM.

```
ansible-playbook --list-tasks playbook.yml
```

Comment: I can't see any such file..?

Answer (score 1):

Ansible logs everything it does on a remote server to syslog. Access your virtual machine and grep syslog with 'ansible-command'. This way you can see exactly what Ansible tasks were run on the virtual machine.