# How to gather all facts on an unknown machine with Ansible?

Tags: python, bash, configuration, installation, ansible

If I start managing a relatively unknown machine, what is the easiest/best way with Ansible and/or Bash or Python to quickly find out what things are installed and what versions?

I'd love to know a generic answer but my two systems of most interest at the moment are RHEL and Mac OSX.

thank you!
ps This SO post only describes how to list what is installed by ansible, ie after I would have taken over. [How to check what installed by Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21515876/how-to-check-what-installed-by-ansible)

Comment: I think `ansible HOST -m setup` should give you all the information that Ansible can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For RedHat (and derivatives) the list of installed packages is available via `rpm -qa` (you probably want to add `| sort` to that for sanity purposes).

For Debian (and derivatives) the list of installed packages is available via `dpkg -l`.

Those only list package installed software. Anything compiled/installed manually will not be in that list and there isn't an easy way to get a list of what those things might be (though looking in `/usr/local` and `/opt` are good places to start).

I don't know of a way to get that sort of list for OS X. Though I imagine the App Store might be a place to start. The Applications folder another.

For `brew` on `OS X` the list of installed packages is available via `brew list`.
For `macports` on `OS X` the list of installed packages is available via `port installed`.

Comment: For _homebrew_ it's `brew list`. For _macports_ it's `port installed`.

Comment: ty! alas I'm worried I will accept these answers :). If I'm really worried about what's there from manual work, am I pretty well stuck with just manually poking around? If so, maybe I need to ask the alternate question, how to keep a system clean and its installations findable? I'm not sure how to word that question though.

Comment: @AnneTheAgile Yes, for anything not installed via some system you can query you are stuck with manual work, previous change documentation and/or asking the previous maintainer. This is why it is generally **strongly** encouraged not to use unpackaged/unmanaged software on production machines and why (to an extent) systems like `ansible`, `chef` and `puppet` were created in the first place.

Comment: Ty! I have tried to organize my apps, but it can get pretty tedious and still unclear at times. On a related topic, I do like that Windows (since 7?) now has the list of MSI-installed programs available with sorting and comments/metadata.